# How to verify retention labels at site level?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, retention, powershell-script

In our SharePoint Online, we have *n* number of sites where retention labels are being assigned for the contents. Though, we are not sure if we have labeled everything and would like to verify what has been labeled and what not.

There seems to be no out of the box report for this and hence would like to get a pointer on how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following steps:

- Log in the [Microsoft 365 compliance center](https://compliance.microsoft.com/)
- Go to **Reports** page from the left navigation
- find **Rentention label usage** -> Show more

[image]

- Select the label you want to check in the Labels list -> Explore items

[image]

- Select **Items with this label** and **location name** in the upcoming page, label usage will be displayed on right.
  [image]

Articles for your reference: [View label usage with label analytics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/label-analytics?view=o365-worldwide)